# Syntax for AND and OR statements in SQLalchemy core?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

How do I write the following SQLite expression in SQLalchemy core?

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id = 1
AND (last_date IS NULL OR
    last_date < date('now', '-30 day') );
```

I saw examples in SQLalchemy orm using the `_and` and `_or` but I wasn't sure if those applied to SQLalchemy core.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators

Answer (score 12):

yes, you can use `sqlalchemy.and_` and `sqlalchemy.or_` on column expressions (note the underscore at the end, not beginning, leading underscores signify non-supported, private api).

You can also use `&` and `|`, the bitwise operators, and they will be compiled in the same fashion as `and_`/`or_`.  Be sure to parenthesize them properly, `&` and `|` have much higher operator precedence than `and` and `or`.

Your code would look a bit like:

```
t.select().where((t.c.id == 1) 
                 & ((t.c.last_date == None)
                    | (t.c.last_date < sa.func.date('now', '-30 day'))))
```

Another option is to treat conjunctive clauses as progressively filtered relations, since the identity:

> σ<sub>a ∧ b</sub>R ↔ σ<sub>b</sub> σ<sub>a</sub>R

you can write that in sqlalchemy as

```
t.select().where(t.c.id == 1) \
          .where((t.c.last_date == None)
                 | (t.c.last_date < sa.func.date('now', '-30 day')))
```

And it produces the same SQL as above.